# Select, count and delete records from table simplify

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I have 3 tables like below:

1) met_ID (primair) etc.

2) magn_ID (primair) 
met_ID (secondary)
...

3) sens_ID (primair) 
met_ID (secondary)
...

I have to delete records in table 1 where met_ID count in table 2 OR 3 is less than 10..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, met_ID
FROM tbl_1, tbl_2
Where met_ID = met_ID
GROUP BY met_ID
```

I made a query and in PHP with WHILE loop i am deleting that records from table 1. It works fine for 1000 records to delete, but I am not sure if it will be use full for 100 000 or more records in table.

Is there any way to accomplish what i do in sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE from tbl_1
WHERE 10 > (select count(*) from tbl_2 where tbl2.met_id=tbl1.met_id) OR
      10 > (select count(*) from tbl_3 where tbl3.met_id=tbl1.met_id)
```

Comment: oh.. maybe i mis interpreted the question.  does he want < 10 of either or < 10 for both combined ?

Comment: I understood as I wrote the query :-) Ask the author better.

Comment: work like a charm... only i mixed up > with < and deleted ~83 000 records from database :-D thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

first use a subquery with having...

secondly, you're not selecting the sum of occurances in table2 and table3
you're doing a cross join, so your count is actually the product...

try this

```
DELETE from table_1 where met_ID IN 
(
  select met_ID FROM
  (
      SELECT met_ID FROM tbl_2   
      union
      select met_id FROM tbl_3
  )
  GROUP BY met_ID
  HAVING count(*) < 10
);
```